# symbol has no Implicit type

Tags: fortran

I'm running this code via fortran 90

```
   Program Projectile
! This Program Calculates the Velocity and Height of a
! Projectile
! Given its Initial Height, Initial Velocity and Constant
! Acceleration.
Implicit None
Real :: Initial_Hight, Height, Initial_Velocity, Velocity, &
Time, Acceleration = -9.807
! Obtain Values for Initial Height, Initial Velocity and
! Time
Print*, "Enter the Initial Height and Velocity:"
Read*, Initial_Height, Initial_Velocity
Print*, "Enter Time at Which to Calculate Height and &
Velocity:"
Read*, Time
! Calculate the Height and Velocity
Height = 0.5 * Acceleration * Time ** 2 + Initial_Velocity &
* Time + Initial_Height
Velocity = Acceleration * Time + Initial_Velocity
! Display Velocity and Height
Print*, "At Time", Time, "The Vertical Velocity is", Velocity
Print*, "and the Height is", Height
End Program Projectile
```

But I constantly get this Error : Error Symbol 'initial_height' has no IMPLICIT type and after erasing implicit none line I can't use real number because real number cause another error, can you help me out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two problems.

As Gilles pointed out, you have a typo in your existing code.

Your second problem is that you do not understand the FORTRAN implicit type rule.  Variables whose names start with I, J, K, L, M, or N are implicitly INTEGER, unless declared otherwise.  All other variables are implicitly REAL, unless declared otherwise.

INITIAL_HEIGHT is implicitly INTEGER, unless you declare it REAL, which you didn't do.  You declared INITIAL_HIGHT to be REAL, and you left INITIAL_HEIGHT undeclared.  Ordinarily, it would be implicitly made INTEGER, which causes a real assignment to barf.  Because you disabled implicit typing altogether, via IMPLICIT NONE, INITIAL_HEIGHT has no type.

And that's what the compiler is trying to tell you.

Comment: This is extremely confusing. It is really just a typo.

Comment: @VladimirF, you are correct that his basic problem was the typo.  However, in order to explain the compiler error messages, it is necessary for him to understand the FORTRAN implicit type rules.

Comment: Explaining *why*s is much more important than the fix itself. +1

Answer (score 2):

You just have a typo in you code here:

```
Real :: Initial_Hight, Height, Initial_Velocity, Velocity, &
  Time, Acceleration = -9.807
```

Which should read

```
Real :: Initial_Height, Height, Initial_Velocity, Velocity, &
  Time, Acceleration = -9.807
```